# What is $R$ in torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, definition, torque

I am confused of what is $R$ in torque is it the distance to the axis of rotation or to a specific point or origin of axis of rotation (pivot)? the forces should treated as lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque is defined as $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{R}\times \mathbf{F}$, where $\mathbf{R}$ is the vector separating an arbitrary reference point at which the torque is measured and the point in which the force $\mathbf{F}$ is applied. Note that $\mathbf{R}$ doesn't need to stem from the axis of rotation unless otherwise specified, and that the cross product $\times$ means that the magnitude of the torque satisfies $|{\boldsymbol{\tau}}| = |\mathbf{R}| |\mathbf{F}|\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle separation between $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{R}$.